# How to have the $Env variable available in the script?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am executing a powershell script using C#, but when I try to get an environment variable inside the powershell script it does not work.

If I run the powershell script manually using the console it works.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Code sample for C#:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

// set directory for ps
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionPath))
    runspace.SessionStateProxy.Path.SetLocation(sessionPath);

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command command = new Command(script, false);
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
pipeline.InvokeAsync();
```

script powershell:

```
$path = $env:PATH;
write-output $path # this is empty ! $env does seems to exist in the runspace ?
```

Comment: I found a workaround by using the script [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382047/1832488) but I would prefer to find how to configure the runspace so the Env variable is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Command command = new Command(script, false);
```

to

```
Command command = new Command(script, true);
```

Your `script` variable is a script (multiple commands).  By passing false, PowerShell thinks that `script` names a command.

Comment: I am passing a .ps1 file path as a command, if I use (script,true) it does not work.

Comment: To make it work, I read the file as string first, then I used Command command = new Command(script, true);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this code instead in your PowerShell script. This should work regardless of how the script is invoked:

```
$path = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path")
write-output $path
```

More info on environment variable manipulation of this kind can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that springs to mind is that you are not passing in a configuration when creating the run space.

```
var config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config);
```

The only thing I've done hosting Powershell was writing unit tests for a Powershell plugin. Code is here: https://github.com/openxtra/TimeTag/tree/master/Test

See DatabasePoSHSnapInTest and PowerStatsPoSHSnapInTest folders for the test projects.

Comment: Did not work either when I create a new configuration and I pass it to my runspace.